# I ask user to enter name of"object" for the data they want to receive. But when I enter "1" the output says "Sorry, invalid input" how can I fix it?

Tags: python, search, data-science

here is my data:

```
|Object |  HJD 24... |    Filter | Magnitude |
|-------| ---------- |-----------|-----------|
|SU_Hor | 55896.30476|      B    |  14.877   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.27438|     Ic    |  13.885   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.27349|      B    |  14.809   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.27397|      V    |  14.434   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.40882|     Ic    |  14.033   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.40829|      V    |  14.540   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.40770|      B    |  14.941   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.34973|     Ic    |  13.958   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.34943|      V    |  14.494   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.34906|      B    |  14.861   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.30542|     Ic    |  13.912   |
|SU_Hor | 55896.30512|      v    |  14.440   |
|SU_Hor | 55897.38547|      V    |  14.536   |
|SU_Hor | 55897.28281|      B    |  14.882   |
|SU_Hor | 55897.28317|      V    |  14.428   |
|SU_Hor | 55897.28347|     Ic    |  13.927   |
|RZ_Lyr | 27359.3030 |      V    |  10.630   |
|RZ_Lyr | 27684.4510 |      V    |  10.610   |
|RZ_Lyr | 27685.4780 |      V    |  10.580   |
|RZ_Lyr | 27701.3150 |      V    |  10.700   |
|RZ Lyr | 27934.4560 |      V    |  10.660   |
|RZ Lyr | 27955.4100 |      V    |  10.570   |
|rzlyr  | 30604.2000 |      V    |  11.030   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55314.5695 |      B    |  12.047   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55314.5724 |      B    |  12.036   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55314.5900 |      B    |  12.042   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55314.6105 |      B    |  12.045   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55314.6163 |      B    |  12.027   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55342.3509 |      B    |  12.057   |
|RZLyr  | 55342.3557 |      B    |  12.058   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55342.3606 |      B    |  12.052   |
|RZ_Lyr | 55342.3654 |      B    |  12.058   |
```

my code:

```
mport csv


def searchByObject():
    object = input('Enter Object name\n')
    csv_file = csv.reader(open("D:/Астрономия Курс 2/PycharmProjects/Python_2ndLab.csv", "r"))

    for column in csv_file:
        if object == column[0]:
            print(column)


def searchByFilter():
    filter = str(input('Enter filter to show data'))
    csv_file = csv.reader(open("D:/Астрономия Курс 2/PycharmProjects/Python_2ndLab.csv", "r"))

    for column in csv_file:
        if filter in column[2]:
            print(column)


print('Enter 1 to search by object name')
print('Enter 2 to search by filter')

src = (input('Enter here: '))

if src == 1:
    searchByObject()
elif src == 2:
    searchByFilter()
else:
    print('Sorry, invalid input')
```

the Output:

- Name: Filter, dtype: object
- Enter 1 to search by object name
- Enter 2 to search by filter
- Enter here: 1
  Sorry, invalid input

**What I expected the Output will be like:**

- Name: Filter, dtype: object
- Enter 1 to search by object name
- Enter 2 to search by filter
- Enter here: 1
- Enter the object name to show data: SU_Hor
  (let's imagine all of the data from SU_Hor appear)

Comment: `src` is a string, you're comparing it with numbers.

Comment: `input` always returns a string, but you compare the value with an integer and a string and an integer will never be equal. Change `if src == 1:` with `if src == '1':`.